# Evaluate the integral $\int\exp(\frac{z^2-3}{z^3}) \, dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

evaluate the integral $\int\exp(\frac{z^2-3}{z^3}) \, dz$ the unit circle oriented counterclockwise.

I think that we use the following theorem:

Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic in an open set containing a circle $C$  and its interior, except for poles at the points $z_1,\ldots,z_N$ inside $C$. Then $$\int_C f(z) \, dz=2\pi i\sum_{k=1}^N \operatorname{Res}(f,z_k)$$

we have only pole $z_0=0$ for $f(z)=\exp(\frac{z^2-3}{z^3})$ and

$$\operatorname{Res}(f,0)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\lim_{z\to0}z^3f(z)$$

Is there another way to evaluate this integral? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The residue method you suggest is fine. But you may not calculate it by the stated formula. The problem is that there is an essential singularity at the origin.

Hint: Several ways to go, but you may e.g. write:
$$ \exp (\frac{z^2-3}{z^3}) = \exp(\frac{1}{z}) \exp(\frac{-3}{z^3})$$
Do a Laurent series expansion (if you know about those?) and pick up the coefficient to $1/z$. [it is in fact quite simple]